# add a slider id to url and show if url with this element is entered jquery

Tags: jquery, url, slider

I have a simple slider and I want that if a certain tab is clicked, the e.g. ID of this element is added to the url. The reason for that is, that I want to be able to have a link that the user can enter and then the desired tab of the slider shows and not always the first tab of the slider.

Here is the example html:

```
<ul id="AuktionenNav">
                    <li><a class="tabSelect one currentNav" href="#Tab0" rel="0">Auktionen starten</a></li>
                    <li><a class="tabSelect two" href="#Tab1" rel="1">Eingestellte Auktionen</a></li>
                </ul>

                    <div class="SlideTab" id="Tab0">
                        <div id="Auktion_Starten">

                        </div><!-- #Auktion_Starten -->
                    </div>

                <div class="SlideTab" id="Tab1">
                    <div id="Eingestellte_Auktionen">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

So I want to be able to show the second tab of the slider if the url the user enters is e.g. xyz.com/#Tab1

I appreciate any help! Thx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this page:
http://articles.rootsmith.ca/mod_python/how-to-make-jquery-ui-tabs-linkable-or-bookmarkable

i think that will help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = '#Tab1';
```